# Multiple Joins with And Statement not working

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I can not seem to get this to work as expected.

```
"SELECT event_positions.id as ep_id, event_positions.pos_prefered_tech, event_positions.assigned_tech_id, "
. "event_schedule.id as es_id, event_schedule.event_id, event_schedule.event_day, event_schedule.event_stime,"
. "event.id as eid, event.crewer_id as cid, event.event_title, event.crewed_by,"
. "crewer.crewer_company"

. "FROM event_schedule "

. "INNER JOIN event_positions "
. "ON event_schedule.id = event_positions.event_sched_id"

. "INNER JOIN event "
. "ON event_schedule.event_id = event.id"

. "INNER JOIN crewer "
. "ON event.crewer_id = crewer.id "

. "WHERE event_schedule.event_day >= NOW() "
. "AND event.crewer_id = ?"
```

**If i remove the AND statement it will pull all data as expected. But I need to filter for the specific crewer_id**

When I try to do this I get an empty result set. No errors.

Comment: Is there a result with this specific `crewer_id` without that condition?

Comment: It seems like there's some spaces missing in the generated SQL text, e.g. before `FROM`,  before `INNER JOIN crewer`. The question mark isn't valid SQL, so likely you are using a prepared statement, and the question mark is bind placeholder. Likely the problem is in the parameter bind. Verify that the value for the bind parameter is one of the values returned when that predicate is not in the statement; also try testing with a literal value, one you know will return rows. I suspect you will find the problem is with the bind parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's some spaces missing in the generated SQL text, for example, before **`FROM`** and before **`INNER JOIN crewer`**.  Are you sure this SQL statement is working?

The question mark character **`?`** doesn't look like valid SQL. So it's likely (and we're going to assume) that this SQL text is for a prepared statement, and that the question mark is intended as a placeholder for a bind variable.

If that's the case, I suspect there's a problem with the parameter bind.

I recommend you verify that the value you are providing for the bind parameter is a value that would return rows, that is, one of the values for `crewer.id` that's returned by the query when this predicate is omitted.

I also suggest you test using a hardcoded literal value, in place of the question mark. Choose a literal value, again, that you know will return rows.

I suspect that when you debug this, you will find the problem is with the bind parameter. (It's only a suspicion, because there's not enough information provided for me to make a determination.)

Comment: You hit it... I just couldn't see it. Fixed the spacing issues and corrected the binding parameter. I was using a $_Session variable and forgot the array key. ugggg... Thank you!!!

Comment: And I have been fiddling with this query for over an hour. I can't believe it.

Comment: For debugging, it's often a good idea to echo out the contents of the string (the SQL text) that's going to be sent to the database. And take that to a different environment to test. That really speeds up identifying the source of the problem you are deubugging.